# Limit lines in a file to some value of characters

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have some file: example.txt with the following content:

```
message(1)
message2(2).ERROR:nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode....blah-blah.verdict fail.
message(3)
```

I get this file as a result of grep:

```
grep -oP 'some regex' source.txt > example.txt
```

What I need is to limit(before writing into file or after) every string to specified number of characters (lets say 20) starting from the end of a line. Something like `tail -c 20` but apply it for every line.

Comment: @anubhava yep - from the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print last 20 characters in a line, you can use:

```
grep -oP 'some regex' source.txt |
awk -v n=20 '{print substr($0, length($0)-n+1, n)}' > example.txt
```